# Jenkins - scriptler plugin access denied to scriptler git repo

Tags: git, authentication, github, jenkins, jcasc

After installing scriptler plugin I want to have my scripts saved in a source repo.

I am trying to clone the default repo of scriptler -https://jenkins.xxxxxxxxxx.com/scriptler.git/

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://jenkins.xxxxxxxxxx.com/scriptler.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

It says I need administrator access, what does it mean? I do have admin access to Jenkins but how does my jenkins creds are connected to git creds?

Another question -> Is it possible to configure my own github repo for scriptler scripts instead of scriptler default repo?